# prevent overriding styles from changing css set styles

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, display

I have a register form made with bootstrap which I validate using ajax and php . If there is an error I display an error message inside my form as a `<span>`.

register.php

```
<form method = "POST" action = "insertUser.php" id ="registerForm">
  ...form inputs 
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id = "submitRegister" name="submit">Submit</button>
 <span id ="checkSubmitError" class= "hide text-danger"> Username already exists . Please insert a new username . 
 </span>


</form>
```

form.css

```
.hide{
  display:none;
}

.show{
  display:block;
}
```

When I submit my form I use ajax and php to check if input already exists . If it does then show the  error message by removing the `.hide` class and adding the `.show` class

.insertUser.php

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['submitRegister'])){
    $alreadyExists = false //suppose user does not exist
    //connect to db and succesfully checks if user exists 
     $alreadyExists = true; //if he exists it is set to true  
    }

  }


  ?>
<script>  //change the class
  var exists = "<?php echo $alreadyExists; ?>";
  if(exists == true){
    if($("#checkSubmitError").hasClass("hide")){
      $("#checkSubmitError").removeClass("hide");
      $("#checkSubmitError").addClass("show");

    }else{
      $("#checkSubmitError").addClass("hide");
    }
  }
  
</script>
```

When this script is executed with intent to display the error ,  it does not appear but the .hide class is removed and the show class is added . By inspecting dev tools I see that the element style is overidden

[image]

By inspecting `utilities.less` I see the folowing :

[image]

So my .hide class is depracated because of the other class which is made from .less . How can I  edit this and make my script work ?

Comment: Use the `hidden` class to hide the element, and _remove_ the class from the element to show it …?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you make your css selector more specific? The more specific the selector the higher the priority (as long as you don't use `!important`, and please don't start using it), this is one of the few cases you can use it because Bootstrap does it already.

You could use `form .show` and `form .hide` for specific form show and hide functionality and add the !important as well to make sure Bootstrap doesn't overwrite it.

Besides that, a few small quick wins:

1. you might want to use a Ternary Operator for this.

`var exists = "<?php echo $alreadyExists; ?>";`

2. Write `if(exists == true)` as `if(exists)`
3. Extract `$("#checkSubmitError")` for unwanted document queries.
4. And simplify the nested if/else

Comment: Voodeckers what do you mean by extracting the $("#checkSubmitError") ?

Comment: @vasilis123 each time you do $(...) jQuery will do a document search for that selector. If you put $("#checkSubmitError") in a variable, you will only have to do it once and it will be easier to maintain when the ID changes, you just have to update one line instead of all occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

try to mark your display property with !**important** flag.

also, make sure that you place your stylesheet at the bottom of your head element to prevent any other library from overriding your styles

Comment: using !important should be avoided as much as possible. Next time you'll have to overwrite the !important and you'll end up in a never ending complexity of rules that are ignored or overwritten by less specific rules. If you have a specific case, the css selector should be specific as well. In this case it should be made more specific AND add the important rule to make sure Bootstrap doesn't overwrite the behaviour and the css doen't overwrite other cases, only the specific one.

Answer (score 0):

.hide and .show where specific classes used in utilities.less By changing their names in my code and adding

```
 else{
      $alreadyExists = true;
      echo "Username already exists "; //added 
    }
```

the code worked